# Test events were not received" when run tests using Intellij

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, junit

Learning Unit testing on android, my tests are not running now, says "Test events were not received, not much details on the stack trace I tried adding and removing some dependencies but did not worked. looked into some other stackoverflow results still not working, I am doing this by following a udemy course on TDD.

Here is one of my test classes

```html
import kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.runBlockingTest
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.runTest
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.mockito.kotlin.mock
import org.mockito.kotlin.times
import org.mockito.kotlin.verify
import org.mockito.kotlin.whenever
import petros.efthymiou.groovy.utils.BaseUnitTest
import petros.efthymiou.groovy.utils.getValueForTest


class PlayListViewModelShould:BaseUnitTest() {


    private val repository: PlayListRepository = mock()
    private val playList = mock<List<PlayList>>()
    private val expected = Result.success(playList)
    private val exception = java.lang.RuntimeException("SOMETHING NOT RIGHT")


    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    @Test
    suspend fun getPlaylistsFromRepository()= runTest{
        val viewModel = mockSuccesfulCase()

        viewModel.playlists.getValueForTest()

        verify(repository,times(1)).getPlaylists()
    }
    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    @Test
    fun emitPlaylistsFromRepository()= runTest {

        val viewModel = mockSuccesfulCase()
        assertEquals(expected, viewModel.playlists.getValueForTest())

    }
    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    @Test
    fun emitErrorWhenRecieveError() {
        runTest {
            whenever(repository.getPlaylists()).thenReturn(
                flow {
                    emit(Result.failure<List<PlayList>>(exception))
                }
            )
        }
        val viewModel = PlayListViewModel(repository)
        assertEquals(java.lang.RuntimeException("another error"), viewModel.playlists.getValueForTest()!!.exceptionOrNull())
    }


    private fun mockSuccesfulCase(): PlayListViewModel {
        runBlocking {
            whenever(repository.getPlaylists()).thenReturn(
                flow {
                    emit(expected)
                }
            )
        }

        return PlayListViewModel(repository)
    }

}
```

My gradle

```html
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "petros.efthymiou.groovy"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    testOptions {
        execution 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'

        unitTests.all {
            useJUnitPlatform()
        }
    }



    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        freeCompilerArgs = freeCompilerArgs + "-Xallow-result-return-type"
    }

    testOptions {
        animationsDisabled = true
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.9'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.espresso:okhttp3-idling-resource:1.0.0'


//    testImplementation 'com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.2.0'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.21.0'
    testImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.3.8'
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.1")
    testImplementation 'org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:4.0.0'
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:4.3.1"
    androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-android:3.10.0"
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.1'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.9.1'


    androidTestImplementation 'com.jakewharton.espresso:okhttp3-idling-resource:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.5.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:4.3.1"

    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3.1"
    androidTestImplementation('com.schibsted.spain:barista:3.6.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin' // Only if you already use Kotlin in your project
    }
}
```

Comment: What do your settings say you are running tests with? Check `Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> "Run tests using"`. Try changing that to gradle if currently on Intellij and Intellij if on gradle.

Comment: I am using the ANdroid studio electric eel version, unfortunately neither Android studio dolphin or electric eel has this option https://imgur.com/a/lNYgysg

Comment: Can you try clearing caches? `File -> Invalidate Caches -> Invalidate and Restart`. This will restart your IDE and cause it to reindex. Then try to run your tests.

Comment: Nope, still the same, actually tried it earlier quite a few times

Comment: when you run the tests, there should be an exception, and you are right, the stack trace is not so helpful, but, if you select the first error/exception that should say something, please share that. When the tests don't run is because there is an exception building.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, able to solve, Some random issue with gradle setup